# When declaring a usage of namespace is required and when it's not?

Tags: clojure

I have two "lein" projects with exactly the same piece of code in two test files:

```
... clojure.set/union ...
```

The first project compiles and runs successfully. The second one errors out with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.set, compiling:(foo/bar.clj:14)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.set
...
```

I can only make the second project run if I add explicit `:use` in `bar.clj`

```
(:use clojure.set)
```

The first project doesn't have this statement though. Why different behaviours?

**UPDATE**:

The first project, where the exception is not happening, has the following declaration in `project.clj`:

```
:eval-in-leiningen true
```

Comment: if you include the namespace declarations from the two projects it would help me improve my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to declare the use of a namespace if you want a local symbol to refer to a name in that namespace. Otherwise you can spell out the full name of each var you want to use. See the first page of http://clojure.org/namespaces

Normal functions are usually stored in `var`s which you can access either by spelling  out the name completely `(clojure.core/+ 1 2)` or by causing a symbol in the enclosing namespace to `refer` to it. As an example we can start with a completely blank namespace called bar. It won't even start with the core Clojure functions in it:

```
foo> (in-ns 'bar)
#<Namespace bar>
bar> (+ 1 2)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: + in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

Though we can use the `+` function if we spell out the full name of the `var` that contains it.

```
bar> (clojure.core/+ 1 2)
3
```

then you can make the symbol `+` refer to the same var it does in clojure.core by calling `refer`

```
bar> (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
nil
bar> (+ 1 2)
3
```

---

As for your errors, situations like this tend to occur when:

- you ran `(use 'clojure.set)` or `(require 'clojure.set)` from the REPL while in that namespace
- the code that calls a function from clojure.set is not actually being called causing you not to see the errors.
- it's declared in the `(ns foo.bar (:use clojure.clj))` form at the top of the file in one project and not in the other

Comment: This isn't true. You have to `require` namespaces you want to use, even if you spell out the whole name of the var you're using. Java classes work the way you said.

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies in Clojure behave much like in most other dynamic languages: until you explicitly *require* a namespace, no symbols from it will be available because the namespace will not have been loaded into the runtime; however, once a namespace is loaded, its symbols are available from **all** namespaces, which explains the behavior you witness. The inconsistency results from the details of the order in which your files are loaded into the runtime.

Other aspects of the namespace dependency issue deal only with the level of convenience with which you dereference the foreign-namespace symbols:

- you can declare a *namespace prefix* to use instead of the full name:

  `(require [clojure.string :as s])`

  This gives you `(s/join "," coll)`
- you can *refer* certain symbols from the foreign namespace into the home namespace. This binds the local symbols to their same-named counterparts in the foreign namespace:

  `(require [clojure.string :refer [join]])`

  which gives you `(join "," coll)`
- you can both declare a prefix and refer specific symbols:

  `(require [clojure.string :as s :refer [join]])`

  which gives you `(join "," coll)` as well as `(s/join "," coll)`
- you can *refer* the whole namespace into your home namespace:

  `(require [clojure.string :refer :all])`

NOTE: the demonstrated syntax works only inside the `(ns ...)` form. When *require* is used as standalone form, all symbols must be explicitly quoted.

As you can see, all you need (as of Clojure 1.4) is *require* and *use* is now just a minor convenience for the cases where you don't need to declare a prefix.

`(use clojure.string)` is the same as `(require [clojure.string :refer :all])`

`(use [clojure.string :only [join]])` is the same as `(require [clojure.string :refer [join]])`.